# Iterate over generic properties of an object validating that is a property of the object and not any string (I receive an error from the compiler)

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors

```
valuesOrCondition$<T>(objects: Observable<T[]>, objectWithPropertiesAndValues: Partial<T>) {

  const properties = Object.keys(objectWithPropertiesAndValues);
  return objects.pipe(  
      map(nodes => nodes.filter(node => 
                                   properties.find(ppName => 
                                   node[ppName] === objectWithPropertiesAndValues[ppName]))),
  );

}
```

When I execute this code TypeScript gives me this error:

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.**

But `objectWithPropertiesAndValues` is `Partial<T>` which means that always will exist on `node` which is `T`.

I understand the problem and I know I can simply add `any` and it will work. But I would like to respect the Typescript way here.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript need certainty sometimes by the developer, that's why you sometimes use `.?` or `!.` in this case you need to specify that the result is `[keyof Partial<T>]` or `[keyof T]`. Just to maintain concordance, use the first one.

Replace this line:

```
const properties = Object.keys(objectWithPropertiesAndValues);
```

for this one:

```
const properties = Object.keys(objectWithPropertiesAndValues) as [keyof Partial<T>];
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Why `Object.keys<T>(o:T)` in Typescript does not returns `[keyof T]` instead?